# JS: click по элементу frame

Tags: javascript, iframe, события

Добрый день!

Помогите решить задачу.

Есть страница, на которой есть фрейм. Фрейм грузит другую страницу. Нужно получить событие нажатия на другую страницу в фрейме.

Пробовал такие варианты:

добавил в фрейм onclick="superFrame()"

```
function superFrame(){
    alert()
}
```

и

добавил в фрейм id='superFrameLink'

```
jQuery(document).on( "click","#superFrameLink", function() {
    alert()

});
```

Варианты не срабатывают.  Как мне получить событие нажатия на элемент фрейма?

Comment: Содержимое во фрейме подгружается с того же домена что и основная страница?

Comment: да, с того же домена что и основная страница

Comment: событие необходимо получить в коде, который на странице во фрейме или на родительской странице?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#superFrameLink').load(function(){
    $('#superFrameLink').contents().on('click', 'body', function(){ alert('click'); });
});
```

Comment: Жаль, но если запросить через консоль после загрузки $('#superFrameLink').contents().on('click', 'body', function(){ alert('click'); }); ничего не происходит. Т.е. событие не вешается.